# Monotouch.Dialog: Background for RadoElement block

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

(from MT examples)

I have a simple dialog which shows a list of desserts. When the desserts is taped the list appears. However, the style of the list of deserts is not the same as the main view where I have a **background** view set for the **tableview**.

Is there a way to style the deserts list tableview background?

```
var root = new RootElement ("Meals") {
new Section ("Dinner"){
        new RootElement ("Dessert", new RadioGroup ("dessert", 2)) {
            new Section () {
                new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "dessert"),
                new RadioElement ("Milkshake", "dessert"),
                new RadioElement ("Chocolate Cake", "dessert")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a subclass of RootElement, and override the PrepareDialogViewController method which is invoked before the controller is presented.   That is where you can customize the background.

Comment: Awesome, I thought it might be something simple like that.